# org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable - JavaSparkContext

Tags: java, serialization, apache-spark

I'm trying to run the following simple Spark code:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
JavaRDD<String> stringRdd = jsc.textFile("src/main/resources/META-INF/data/supplier.json");

JavaRDD<SupplierDTO> rdd = stringRdd.map(new Function<String, SupplierDTO>()
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -78238876849074973L;

    @Override
    public SupplierDTO call(String str) throws Exception
    {
        return gson.fromJson(str, SupplierDTO.class);
    }
});
```

But it's throwing the following error while executing the `stringRdd.map` statement:

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable
at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:166)
at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:158)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:1478)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.map(RDD.scala:288)
at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike$class.map(JavaRDDLike.scala:78)
at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD.map(JavaRDD.scala:32)
at com.demo.spark.processor.cassandra.CassandraDataUploader.uploadData(CassandraDataUploader.java:71)
at com.demo.spark.processor.cassandra.CassandraDataUploader.main(CassandraDataUploader.java:47)
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1184)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializationStream.writeObject(JavaSerializer.scala:42)
at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.serialize(JavaSerializer.scala:73)
at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:164)
... 7 more
```

Here 'jsc' is the `JavaSparkContext` object I'm using.
As far as I know, `JavaSparkContext` is not a `Serializable` object and one should not use it inside any functions which will be sent to the Spark workers.

Now, what I'm not able to understand is, how the instance of `JavaSparkContext` is being sent to the workers? What should I change in my code to avoid such scenario?

Comment: Are you sure that's all the log? I think it's Gson that is causing the problem, since I have ran into the same problem before.

Comment: Here's the full log.

Comment: can you paste the SupplierDTO class here?

Comment: @Sathish: It's just a pojo and serializable..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `gson` reference is 'pulling' the outer class into the scope of the closure, taking its full object graph with it.

In this case, create the gson object within the closure:

```
public SupplierDTO call(String str) throws Exception {   
   Gson gson = Gson();
   return gson.fromJson(str, SupplierDTO.class);
}
```

You can also declare the spark context `transient`

If the creation of the Gson instance is costly, consider using `mapPartitions`  instead of `map`.

Comment: Creating the Gson object within the call method is not making any difference. Neither the other two options you mentioned. Please help.

Comment: @ArkaGhosh adding `transient` to the declaration of the `sparkContext` should -at least- change the exception being thrown.

Comment: can you please mention the fully classified name of that `transient` annotation.

Comment: @ArkaGhosh `transient` is a keyword in Java. You use it like: `transient JavaSparkContext context = new ....`

Comment: My bad.. I thought you were talking about the `transient` annotation.. let me try with that again..

Comment: @maasg Could you please explain more about making JavaSparkContext as transient?

Comment: Setting the SparkContext variable to `transient` solved the probleme for me.

Answer (score 4):

For me I resolved this problem using one of the following choices:

1. As mentioned above, by declaring SparkContext as `transient`
2. You could also try to make the object gson static
   `static Gson gson = new Gson();`

Please refer to the doc [Job aborted due to stage failure: Task not serializable](https://databricks.gitbooks.io/databricks-spark-knowledge-base/content/troubleshooting/javaionotserializableexception.html)

to see other available choices to resolve this probleme

Comment: I too had same issue. I marked my context reference as transient. I worked

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code instead of line 9.(`return gson.fromJson(str, SupplierDTO.class);`)

```
return new Gson().fromJson(str, SupplierDTO.class);//this is correct
```

and remove line 1.(`Gson gson = new Gson();`)